# Jetpack Compose Slider performance

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

Using LiveData to store the value of the slider makes it lag and move jerky (I suppose because of postValue ())

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    viewModel: MyViewModel
) {
    val someValue = viewModel.someValue.observeAsState()
    
    Slider(someValue) {
        viewModel.setValue(it)
    }
}

class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val someValue: LiveData<Float> = dataStore.someValue // MutableLiveData
    fun setValue(value: Float) {
        dataStore.setValue(value)
    }
}

class MyDataStore() {
    val someValue = MutableLiveData<Float>()
    fun setValue(value: Float) {
        // Some heavy logic 
        someValue.postValue(value)
    }
}
```

As I understand it, postValue() takes a while, and because of this, the slider seems to be trying to resist changing the value.

In order to somehow get around this, I had to create additional State variables so that the slider would directly update its value

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    viewModel: MyViewModel
) {
    val someValue = viewModel.someValue.observeAsState()
    var someValue2 by remember { mutableStateOf(someValue) }

    
    Slider(someValue2) {
        someValue2 = it
        viewModel.setValue(it) // I also had to remove postValue ()
    }
}
```

As I understand it, if the data from the DataStore comes with a delay, then the value in someValue will not have time to initialize and it will be null by the time the view appears (this has not happened yet, but is it theoretically possible?), And thus the value of the slider will not be relevant. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: All in all, you are completely right in your thinking. I would also move `someValue2` to the view model, because the view doesn't need to know about your data store

Comment: Have you tried using `setValue` instead of `postValue`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is now an old question. I also ran into the same kind of trouble   as I was using Coroutine Flow to update the Slider progress in my music app. Once the value of slider is connected to a Flow which is updating every second, seeking it to a new value was making it lag. I found the solution by using a second local variable instead of Flow while seeking is done and then re-attaching the Flow variable once seeking is done. For example -

```
val currentMediaProgress = viewModel.currentMediaProgress.collectAsState()
var currentPos = currentMediaProgress.value //original variable
val currentPosTemp = remember { mutableStateOf(0f)} //temporary variable

     Slider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = if (currentPosTemp.value == 0f) currentPos else currentPosTemp.value,
            onValueChange = {
                Log.d(LOG, "seek to --> $it")
                currentPosTemp.value = it
            },
            onValueChangeFinished = {
                currentPos = currentPosTemp.value
                currentPosTemp.value = 0f
                //send the currentPos value for updating the Slider progress
            },
        )
```

Using this logic, while seeking is happening, value of Slider is detached from the Flow variable which was the reason for lagging (in my case because I was constantly updating the Slider every second). When seeking is finished, setting the temp variable to 0f will reattach the Flow variable for continuing Slider progress.

Comment: This is perfectly working fine !!